# Elasticsearch bad request on mapping put method

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nest

I m trying to create an index in Elastic Search and to add analyzer and maaping to handle special characters like @ to search on Email field. Here is my code

**Analyzer.txt**

```
{
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "email_search": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
            "filter": [ "lowercase", "stop" ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapping.txt**

```
{"users": 
 {
  "properties": {
  "email": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "email_search"
  }
 }
}
```

**CreatedIndex**

```
string _docuementType ="users";
string _indexName="usermanager";
public bool Index(T entity)
    {
        SetupAnalyzers();
        SetupMappings();
        var indexResponse = _elasticClient.Index(entity, i => i.Index(_indexName)
                                                                  .Type(_docuementType)
                                                                  .Id(entity.Id));


        return indexResponse.IsValid;
    }
```

**SetupAnalyzer**

```
protected void SetupAnalyzers()
    {
        if (!_elasticClient.IndexExists(_indexName).Exists)
        {
            _elasticClient.CreateIndex(_indexName);
        }

        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
           string analyzers = File.ReadAllText("analyzers.txt");
           client.UploadData("http://localhost:9200/usermanager/_settings", "PUT", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(analyzers));
        }
    }
```

**SetupMappings**

```
protected void SetupMappings()
    {
        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var mappings = File.ReadAllText("mappings.txt");
            client.UploadData("http://localhost:9200/usermanager/users/_mapping", "PUT", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mappings));
        }
    }
```

But getting error on **SetupMappings** method

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Elastic version is 1.7.5

Nest version is 5.5

Comment: You need to use NEST 1.x version with Elasticsearch 1.7.5. see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/readme.md#compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
var indexResponse = _elasticClient.Index(entity, i => i.Index(_indexName)
                                                       .Type(_docuementType)
                                                       .Id(entity.Id));
```

You're indexing documents *before* setting up the mapping and analyzers; in this case, Elasticsearch will automatically create the index, infer a mapping from the first document it sees and string properties will be mapped as [analyzed string fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-core-types.html#string) using the standard analyzer.

To fix this, you should create the index, analyzers and mappings *before* indexing any documents. You can also [disable auto index creation if you need to, in elasticsearch.yml config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-index_.html#index-creation). It depends on your use case as to whether this is might be a good idea; a search use case with known indices and explicit mappings is a case where you might consider disabling it.

So, the procedural flow would be something like

```cs
void Main()
{
    var indexName = "usermanager";
    var typeName = "users";

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .MapDefaultTypeNames(d => d
            // map the default index to use for the User type
            .Add(typeof(User), typeName)
        )
        .MapDefaultTypeIndices(d => d
            // map the default type to use for the User type
            .Add(typeof(User), indexName)
        );

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (!client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
    {
        client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(aa => aa
                    .Add("email_search", new CustomAnalyzer
                    {
                        Tokenizer = "uax_url_email",
                        Filter = new [] { "lowercase", "stop" } 
                    })
                )
            )
            .AddMapping<User>(m => m
                .Properties(p => p
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Email)
                        .Analyzer("email_search")
                    )
                )
            )   
        );
    }

    client.Index(new User { Email = "me@example.com" });
}

public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }       
}
```

which will send the following requests (assuming index doesn't exist)

```
HEAD http://localhost:9200/usermanager

POST http://localhost:9200/usermanager
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "email_search": {
            "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stop"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "analyzer": "email_search",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST http://localhost:9200/usermanager/users
{
  "email": "me@example.com"
}
```

**NOTE: You will need to delete the index and recreate, in order to change the mapping.** It's a good idea to use aliases to interact with indices, so that you can iterate on mappings whilst developing.

Comment: Russ, even if i call **SetupAnalyzers(); SetupMappings();** before creating an index it still gives me same error

Comment: Can you update your question to show what you're doing?

Comment: > The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
There is something wrong with the request sent to Elasticsearch in this case. You should inspect the response returned from Elasticsearch to see what the issue is, but first, you need to use a NEST 1.x version with Elasticsearch 1.7.5. **NEST 5.5 is not compatible with 1.7.5**